# How to fix 'MediaPlayrer mp = new Mediaplayer.create(this, R.raw.filename.mpr) ' as create is with red as a error

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create a new object of Media player class but i have this error message on

```
MediaPlayer.create: cannot resolve symbol 'create'
```

My code

```
MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.filename.mp3);
mp.start();
```

I want an mp3 file to play music when my activity started

Comment: Use `new` or `Create`, not both.

Comment: also, do not use file name extension i.e. mp3. only write R.raw.filename in create method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct is:

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.filename.mp3); 
mp.start();
```

The word **`new`** only constructor.

Answer (score 1):

As you are playing audio from raw resources you need to use below code. Make sure your file is saved in your application's `res/raw/` directory

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.sound_file_1);
mediaPlayer.start();
```